# Android QR Code scanner, the background color is half-transparent, how to set a specific area full transparent?

Tags: android

not sure if anyone can give me some advice?

[This is UI design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQO8S.jpg)

The background is an ImageView.

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:alpha="0.1"
    android:background="#FF000000" />
```

The scanner area is an ImageView too.

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/scan_view_finder"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/scanningframe" />
```

This is scanningframe code.

[@drawable/scanningframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18XLR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solution ideas:

- Use a bitmap, iterate over all the pixels and gray out the ones which are not inside of the view.

  - (+) code only
  - (-) hard to implement
  - (-) might take some time
- Light the area up (using white background color with transparency) as much as you darkened the screen

  - (+) easy to implement
  - (-) might cause color accuracy loss
- Use 4 views around the area to darken the background

  - (+) easy to implement
  - (-) takes more views than wanted
- Create a bitmap with the metrics of the area and draw the whole image on it, so you get a smaller piece of the image.

  - (+) easier to implement than the first bitmap idea (you just need to calculate the middle)
  - (-) might take some time

**Edit for point 3**

```
- horizontal linearlayout
    - view
    - vertical layout
        - view
        - area
        - view
    - view
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, looks like all of these solutions will take lots of time. If there is no other easier solution then I'll just switch to another scanner library.

Comment: @MichaelChou
You should be able to implement the 3rd one very easily (view answer edit)

This is the easiest solution to make (implemented in 5 minutes) and you won't find any other library that does that for you because this is a very specific problem. And even if, it won't be worth the effort

Comment: Let me try your suggestion and tell you the answer later. Thank you.